# bootstrap 3 navbar static top change to fixed top when scroll with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have a script to make bootstrap 3 navbar static top change to fixed top when scroll

```
document.onscroll = function() {
if( $(window).scrollTop() > $('header.banner').height() ) {
    $('header.banner').removeClass('navbar-static-top').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
}
else {
    $('header.banner').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top').addClass('navbar-static-top');
}
};
```

but how to add the animation when change to fixed top?
thx

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?  If so, how I would go about this would be different to how I would do it with just jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap I would look into the [`affix` plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)

Failing that, you can do it using your code like this, I am using animate but you could just as easily use some fading, the key part is that I am not adding the `fixed-top` until the animation is complete. [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) all have callback functions.  If needed, you can chain animations together using the callback.

Also another thing worth noting is that I declared the variable `header = $('header.banner');` at the top, this will speed things up a little since you're not making jQuery find the item every time you are using it. Over the course of a large-ish js file, using variables like this can really speed up your script.

Finally play with the animation speed to get the effects you need.

```
document.onscroll = function() {
    var header = $('header.banner')
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > header.height() ) {
         header.animate({
             // place your own css styles here
             opacity: 0.5,
         }, 5000, function() {
             header.removeClass('navbar-static-top').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
         }
    }
    else {
         header.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top').addClass('navbar-static-top');
    }
};
```

Comment: yes i'm using bootstrap 3.2. and i dont know why the script is not working for me, is there any solution? thx